# auditd installation issue on docker image

Tags: software-installation

I have ubuntu docker images for 16.04 and 16.10. I am installing the auditd service on this images but getting this error.

```
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package libauparse0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 6501 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libauparse0_1%3a2.6.6-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libauparse0:amd64 (1:2.6.6-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package auditd.
Preparing to unpack .../1-auditd_1%3a2.6.6-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking auditd (1:2.6.6-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libauparse0:amd64 (1:2.6.6-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up auditd (1:2.6.6-1ubuntu1) ...
**update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported;falling back to defaults
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.**
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-0ubuntu1) .
```